# SQL / Power BI tracking completion time of project

Tags: sql, powerbi, directquery

I am trying to put the information on scheduled vs actual completion time of different projects into a Power BI dashboard using Direct Query. I have a table that has the scheduled and actual start and finish times but something happens when I move it to Power BI that I am not understanding.

I am using datepart(hour, columnname) inside microsoft ssms for both the scheduled and actual start and finish times on a per project basis from my table that has around 400,000 projects. The output looks fine in SQL, it gives me different values for the scheduled and actual columns in many cases, but when I move the query into Power BI and try to display it on a clustered column chart with region as the x axis and count of the time columns as the y axes, it gives me the exact same count for both values in every region. Doing a 5 second look at the output in SQL, I know for a fact that this is not the case. I do not want to modify the dashboard with DAX because it turns it into an import query and I have the direct queries set up to refresh every hour. What am I doing wrong here? I am pretty comfortable with SQL but fairly new to Power BI... Any input would be appreciated, cheers.